# show thumbnail and text align

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

here it's my code:

```
<div class = "menu-content">
        <ul data-role = "listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role = "list-divider">Emergency Menù</li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                        <img src="assets/icns/user.png" class = "ui-li-icons" />

                    Add 
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

the user.png icons ia png file of 32x32px.I would display inline thumbnail and the text Add. my problem is when I align the thumbnail the text remain to top.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Try using style="float:left;" on the image.

Also I'm seeing the class as ui-li-icons. Are you trying to create a class just for the image within the ul?

You could do css like:

```
#menu li img {/*CSS HERE*/}
```

#menu being the ul.

Comment: I add the example. as you see the text is at the top. I would center it.

Comment: I used as you suggest me: float: left

Answer (score 0):

Check your vertical align on the text.

```
vertical-align:baseline
vertical-align:middle
```

I sometimes have to mess with those settings to align things right.